# Asp.Net Repeater not showing its element

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asprepeater

I am using ASP.NET repeater and I want to display simply  heading 
like this:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h3>Example1</h3>

        <asp:Repeater ID="rp1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rp1_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <h4>Repeater Data</h4>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </form>
</body>
```

But when I run my code its shows only  heading and avoid inner  heading. I know Its quiet simple to solve this but believe me I googling after an hours but not found any solution. Kindly help me.

Comment: Could you show your code behind? I think your repeater bind is not good.

Answer (score 1):

`ItemTemplate` is shown only when `Repeater` has data.

What you want to use is `HeaderTemplate` instead, which is also visible when no data is present.

In your previous `ItemTemplate` include only the data you want to display per item.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rp1" runat="server">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <h4>Repeater Data</h4>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Same results no data visible.

Comment: `<h4>` is not present? inspect the html you got at browser to see if it's hidden or if it is not there at all (F12 to open developer console)

Comment: Did you run your example? Is it running well?

Comment: Header and footer templates should display always by default. Check in all page lifecycle not being settig repeater's Visible property to false. Also not from javascript/jquery. Also, which version of the framework are you using? And lately, does the repeater shows up when it actually brings data?